# Exclude elements from display none

Tags: css

I used the same code in my site:

```css
.title_hero {
  display: none;
}
```

I want to exclude this property for some pages which have the class: id-1 and class: id-2. How to do this?

Comment: Can we see the HTML as well please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
.id-1 .title_hero, .id-2 .title_hero {
    display: block;
}

title_hero {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the structure, this could do nothing (for example if the `title_hero` element is an ancestor of `.id-1`).

Comment: Sure it does, but OP said the page has the class, and the page it's usually higher in the hierarchy. I just gave the best answer I could, based on the information which was given :)

Answer (score 1):

This will select all `.title_hero` that don't have the `id-1` or `id-2` class:

```css
.title_hero:not(.id-1):not(.id-2) {
  display: none;
}
```